# Reputable web host in mainland China?

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting, customer-service

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

We currently have a rather poorly set up Windows 2003 box with little to no support based in Shanghai; with no control panel/mail server.

I am told for legal/business reasons the host must be based in the same location as the company for the website; but this could well be misinformation.

Are there any well-known, quality hosts in China that offer reliable English-speaking support? We did consider GoDaddy on the west coast of America, but were informed of the risk of the site being shut down without any notice.

We don't have any technically-minded contacts out there to advise, and hoping that someone will have some more experience in this department. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon EC2 allows you to deploy a cloud server to Singapore.  That should be your closest bet to china, while using a very reliable american company. 
http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#details

Windows Azure Cloud servers also has an AsiaPacific region. 
They dont really tell you where the servers are located, but this Q&A answer will give you some details.   Windows Azure cloud servers can be dirt cheap specially if your business qualifies for Microsoft BizSpark.  Last i checked (around september 2012) the Azure cloud servers had issues when running linux (read only disk errors).  I am sure MSFT has figured this out by now.  Its still in beta, but its BLAZING FAST.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazuremanagement/thread/b231fd5f-3104-43d6-8b45-e97776967013